# Why Storm backtype.storm.utils.TimeCacheMap deprecated

Tags: java, apache-storm

Why Storm deprecated timecachemap;
details https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/blob/moved-to-apache/storm-core/src/jvm/backtype/storm/utils/TimeCacheMap.java

Is there any bugs with this class?

Comment: There's a comment in the source: "deprecated in favor of non-threaded RotatingMap"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was the real reason. Seems like it exposes a generic set of capabilities, not really essential to Storm. I've implemented simple join bolts using [Guava Cache](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) and was very satisfied.